# Core web vitals - Mobile - CLS issue: more than 0.25 (mobile)

Tags: performance, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

About two weeks ago, our web core vitals suddenly started showing 224 poor url's with CLS issue: more than 0.25 (mobile).
When we check the pagespeed insights for some of these url's, they continue to display good overall scores of about 95/100 for mobile.
The Cumulative Layout Shift scores are on average 0.0004 too.
We do not understand why these mobile url's are being flagged as poor by Google Search Console.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66692021/2702894 - the first sentence explains it, on the synthetic test it just loads the page and tests, in the real world it monitors CLS until the page unload event. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65689435/2702894 has some further info and ways to track.

Comment: Thanks for the info Graham. We'll check out the other posts that you've recommended.

Comment: You might also find this post useful, it goes into details as to why Core Web Vitals data can be different between lab tools (like PSI) and field tools showing real-user data (like Search Console): https://web.dev/lab-and-field-data-differences/

Comment: Thanks Philip, we'll have a look at the post. We appreciate your feedback.